Lit Code Highligher: Slot content not visible in firstUpdated() function
Below is the Lit Element I'm trying to make to display a codeblock with Prism.js code highlighting. For some reason the slot content is not showing up in the firstUpdated() function when I query the #code element. I can run the same code in the dev tools console and I do see the content so I'm not really sure why it isn't working in the firstUpdated() function.
The Lit docs mention to use firstUpdated() to access slot content: https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/#accessing-nodes-in-the-shadow-dom
Here is the html markup
<tb-code-block language="markup">
    <div>slot content</div>
    <span>here</span>
</tb-code-block>

import { LitElement, html, css } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";
import * as Prism from "prismjs";
import "prismjs/components/prism-r.min.js";
import "prismjs/components/prism-javascript.min.js";
import "prismjs/components/prism-markup.min.js";

type LanguageOption = "r" | "javascript" | "markup";

@customElement("tb-code-block")
export class CodeBlock extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
    #hide {
      display: none !important;
    }
  `;

  @property({ type: String }) language: LanguageOption = "javascript";
  @property({ type: String }) theme: string = "/node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism.css";;
  @property({ type: Boolean }) lineNumbers = false;

  firstUpdated() {
    
    if (!this.shadowRoot) return;
    const code = this.shadowRoot!.querySelector(
      "#code",
    ) as HTMLSlotElement | null;
    // console.log('code',code); => slot id="code"></slot>
    let nodes = code!
      .assignedNodes() as HTMLElement[];
       
    // console.log('nodes',nodes); => []

    let codeCombined = "";
    for (let index = 0, len = nodes.length; index < len; ++index) {
      codeCombined += nodes[index].innerHTML;
    }
    codeCombined = codeCombined.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    // console.log('codeCombined',codeCombined); => ""

    if (this.language && Prism.languages[this.language]) {
      const highlight = Prism.highlight(
        codeCombined,
        Prism.languages[this.language],
        this.language,
      ) as string;
      // console.log('highlight',highlight); => ""

      const output = this.renderRoot.querySelector(
        "#output",
      ) as HTMLElement | null;
      if (output) {
        output.innerHTML = highlight;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="${this.theme}" />
      <pre class="language-${this.language}"><code id="output"></code></pre>

      <div id="hide">
        <slot id="code"></slot>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}


I copied the code here and seems to log assigned nodes. https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=93ace68074ce367fd5856d2c07eb7c9d
